# DOM hash url in entry slug

Tags: craft3, entry, url, slug, hash

I try to set the **slug** of an **entry** to a url using a hash.

https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-url-hash

However it seems not possible by default, craftcms changes the hash to a dash.

I need that as fragment param for my javascript.

I have searched and read the docs but cannot find any hint to change this behaviour

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible (not only in Craft, but in general) because the fragment (hash, the part after the `#`) is **only used on the client-side**. This is by design, it's part of the spec that the fragment is never sent to the server. The server never knows about the fragment, so it can't do routing based on it.

Using a fragment for routing is only possible if you have some sort of single-page-application which does routing in the frontend. In this case, the routing is done with JavaScript which *does* have access to the fragment, so it can route to a particular component based on it. Doing that on the backend (server-side) is impossible.

Comment: Indeed, but this has nothing to do with my problem... Added hint that I use the param via javascript

Comment: @HonsaStunna Please expand on what you're trying to do. If you simply want to include a fragment in an URL somewhere on your site, you have to do that in your template where you output the link, not in the entry.

Comment: I need that url to go to the anchor depending on the object delivered from the craft db. Just as standard location hash https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash

Comment: I will use an additional field, thx for your help

Comment: @HonsaStunna Still curious about your use-case. If you describe your intended structure in more detail, I'm sure I can provide a good solution. But yeah, using an extra field sounds reasonable.

Comment: Onepager (section) with category anchors, open via switch or url with hash. Parent section childs with content of the categories is the "entry" or category overview. In this entry I want to define the default category. Easiest way i thought, adding the hash to the slug ;)

Comment: @HonsaStunna If it's a onepager, you can just use the entry slugs as fragments. Just output an ID based on the entry slug in your HTML code, then you can link to the specific sections by building a link with the slug as the fragment.